# Automatically un-mount SDCard safely when device is rebooted or turned off?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sd-card, automation

How can I configure my Galaxy S II so every time my device is either rebooted or turned off the SDCard is safely un-mounted because at the moment if I don't un-mount it, the files on SDCard appear as duplicated for some reason.

My device is rooted with Ressurction Remix 2.6.1 with Siyah Kernel 3.2.7.2.

Comment: If you shut-down your device (i.e. either switch it of or reboot it), the system takes care for that -- except, of course, if you shut-down by taking out the battery.

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS is supposed to do this automatically for you unless the device is powered down or rebooted incorrectly (eg. removing the battery). Ive never heard of files being doubled on an SD card after rebooting before. I would suggest trying a different ROM since your phone is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

If files are being doubled, why are you asking about safe unmounting? Problems caused by no safe unmounting are file system corruption, data loss etc. Files aren't doubled by it.

I haven't heard of such type of problem before. Its possible that an app or a shell script is doubling files at the time of boot. To pin-point the problem, turn off the device, remove the sdcard and check with PC that files are doubled or not. If files are doubled, it means something is doing this at time of shut down. Do this: Turn off device by pulling out battery and then boot. Tell me the result.

Comment: Pulling the battery out of an Android phone while it's on is [not advisable](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5103/if-i-pull-the-battery-out-the-sd-card-file-system-crashs-all-file-lost)

Comment: Its a troubleshooting step which isn't advisable during normal situations...